# React app wrapped in Wordpress template leads to css problems

Tags: wordpress, twitter-bootstrap, reactjs

I have created a web app with ReactJs which I now want to make a part of a Wordpress page. The web app ist styled using react bootstrap.

The idea was:
To use a wordpress template which just renders the div where my App loads into:

**Wordpress Template:**

```
<div id="app"> </div>
```

Styling for the App is restricted to the div "app":

```
#app { 
//Bootstrap css + additional css used for the app
 }
```

This way the style of my App doesn't interfere with the css of the wordpress template and the Header / Footer of the Page look perfect.

**The problem:**

The css of the wordpress theme conflict with the bootstrap css used in the div "app". Because of this the web app looks like a mess.

Is there an (easy) way to ignore the css of the wordpress template within the app div?

Comment: React does not influence the css, so this is really not a react question.